# Is there a Facebook deveploment email list

Tags: facebook, list, sharing, mailing

A mailing list for when Facebook deploys changes to their sharing buttons/features would be extremely useful. *Sometimes* the changes made by Facebook alters the performance of our site and I would like to run tests when changes are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/support/community/ it isn't a mailing list per se, but there's a number of ways there for you to keep up to date on FB tech happenings.

Cheers!

Cynthia